# Как написать скрипт на раскрытие такой формы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В начале имеется такая форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После фокуса она становится такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал блок с формой `position:relative`, при фокусе увеличил ширину и длину, далее создал блок с двумя элементами формы `input` и `button`. Дал этому блоку абсолютное позиционирование, разместил как нужно. В итоге при фокусе я показываю этот блок с элементами форм, а при `blur` я убираю его. Но возникла такая проблема, что я не могу нажимать на сами элементы формы, ведь тогда происходит событие `blur` и форма сворачивается, элементы естественно пропадают.

P.S. Открывать надо на весь экран, а то плохо видно, это кусок верстки.
P.S.S На адаптив не смотрите, он тут не требуется :)

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('.send_place textarea');
console.log(textarea);
textarea.addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == 'TEXTAREA' || event.target.tagName == 'INPUT' || event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    var hiddenTextareaElements = document.querySelector('.hidden_send_place');
    hiddenTextareaElements.style.display = 'block';
    var deletteLinks = document.querySelector('.footer_number_email');
    deletteLinks.style.display = 'none';
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
textarea.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == 'TEXTAREA' || event.target.tagName == 'INPUT' || event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    var hiddenTextareaElements = document.querySelector('.hidden_send_place');
    hiddenTextareaElements.style.display = 'none';
    var deletteLinks = document.querySelector('.footer_number_email');
    deletteLinks.style.display = 'block';
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```css
footer {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 18px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 60px
}

footer .footer_links {
  float: left
}

footer .footer_links ul {
  list-style: none
}

footer .footer_links ul li a {
  color: #474747;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px
}

footer .footer_links ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 200px
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .footer_album_links ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .footer_album_links ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .footer_album_links ul li:first-child a {
  position: relative
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .footer_album_links ul li:first-child a:after {
  content: '-';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #474747;
  top: -3px;
  right: -9px
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .footer_album_links ul li:last-child a {
  position: relative
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .footer_album_links ul li:last-child a:before {
  content: '-';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #474747;
  top: -3px;
  left: -9px
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .footer_album_links ul li a {
  color: #474747;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .footer_album_links ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .copyright {
  margin-top: 40px
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .copyright p {
  font-size: 16px
}

footer .footer_album_links_copyright .copyright p span {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

footer .footer_contacts {
  float: right;
  text-align: right
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_contact_send h6 {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_contact_send .send_place {
  margin-top: 8px;
  position: relative
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_contact_send .send_place i {
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #cfd4ed;
  transform: translateY(-4px) rotate(180deg);
  cursor: auto
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_contact_send .send_place textarea {
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #cfd4ed;
  border-radius: 3px;
  resize: none;
  width: 82px
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_contact_send .send_place textarea:focus {
  height: 66px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_contact_send .send_place .hidden_send_place {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  display: none
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_contact_send .send_place .hidden_send_place input {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff7519;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 21px;
  bottom: 0
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_contact_send .send_place .hidden_send_place button {
  width: 86px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff7519;
  position: absolute;
  color: #ff7519;
  font-size: 14px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_number_email {
  margin-top: 10px
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_number_email a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #294ca5;
  font-size: 14px
}

footer .footer_contacts .footer_number_email a:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #294ca5;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px
}
```

```html
<footer class="clearfix">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer_links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Как работать на портале (справка)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Торговые инструменты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Рекламные площади</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Партнерская программа</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_album_links_copyright">
      <div class="footer_album_links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Правила публикации товаров</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Пользовательское соглашение</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Политика конфиденциальности</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        <p>© 2017 <span>neftemoll.ru.</span> Все права защищены.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_contacts">
      <div class="footer_contact_send">
        <h6>Обратная связь</h6>
        <div class="send_place">
          <i class="icon-duble-arrow"></i>
          <textarea></textarea>
          <div class="hidden_send_place">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" required>
            <button>Отравить</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer_number_email">
        <a href="tel:880007777777">(8)-800-777-77-77</a>
        <a href="mailto:corporation@mail.ru">corporation@mail.ru</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант, 
таб работать не будет

```
textarea.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName == 'TEXTAREA' || event.target.tagName == 'INPUT' || event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
        //блок расширяется появляются поля
    }else{
        //блок сужается поля пропадают
    }
});
```

Comment: А почему таб не будет работать?

Comment: насколько я знаю при смене поля при помощи таб на поле срабатывает только фокус